# Can I have a timezone-aware datetime.date object?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a situation where I want to store dates, but I also want them to be timezone-aware?  Do I have to use `datetime.datetime` for this, or can I have a `datetime.date` object that is timezone-aware?

Comment: Why would I try it when StackOverflow is more efficient and can also be useful for others?

Comment: Because you would have been able to answer your own question is why.

Comment: How does that benefit me or anyone else when StackOverflow is faster?

Comment: Do you raise your own chickens?

Comment: No, and nor am I taking up other people's time asking questions about the subject I could easily answer myself -- even if I thought others might benefit by my asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot have a timezone-aware `datetime.date` object.

A date *cannot* be timezone aware, because it's only the *time of day* that differs from zone to zone, dragging the date with it as needed.

In other words: March 1st is March 1st in any timezone. A given geographical location may arrive at that date at a different *time*, but take away the time component and all you have is 3 numbers: a year, a month and a day.

Comment: What you say doesn't make sense, as that date also differs between timezones.

Comment: @AbhishekRam: What, so March 1st is suddenly not March 1st in another timezone? It may be March 1st *later* or *earlier* there, but that is a *property of **time***. A `date` object has no property of time anymore.

Comment: @AbhishekRam: This is like saying that today's 12 o'clock is different from yesterday's 12 o'clock. Both are *just time values*, hours = 12, minutes = 0, seconds = 0. You need the date *and* a timezone in addition, but then you have a `datetime` object again.

Answer (score -2):

The date object does not accept timezones, however we can workaround this by creating a datetime object that is timezone aware and then using its date function to get a date object.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
datetime_obj = datetime.now(timezone('US/Eastern'))
date_obj = datetime_obj.date()
```

Comment: The `date` object doesn't differ just because it was taken from a timezone-aware `datetime` object. It only *has* `year`, `month` and `day` attributes. A US/Eastern date **is no different** from a India Standard Time date.